# js динамический подсчет input type="radio"

Tags: javascript, radio

Сейчас подсчет в коде идет по кнопке. Как сделать подсчет динамическим?

```html
    <input type="radio" name="aa" value='1'>
    <input type="radio" name="aa" value='2'>
    
    <input type="radio" name="bb" value='1'>
    <input type="radio" name="bb" value='2'>
    
    <input type='button' value='=' onclick='calc()' >
    <input type="text" id='trouble_itog' readonly>
```

```
    function getaa(aa)
    {
        var elements = document.getElementsByName(aa);
        for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++)
        {if (elements[i].checked){return elements[i].value;}}
    }
    
    function getbb(bb)
    {
        var elements = document.getElementsByName(bb);
        for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++)
        {if (elements[i].checked){return elements[i].value;}}
    }
    
    function calc()
    {
        result = 
        Number(getaa("aa")) +
        Number(getbb("bb"));
        
        document.getElementById('trouble_itog').value = result;
    }
```

Comment: Зачем Вы написали две одинаковые функции с разными названиями параметра?

Comment: я подумал, что раз два блока радиокнопок, то и обработка должна быть в разных функциях getaa(aa), getbb(bb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getRadioValue(name) {
  let elements = document.getElementsByName(name);
  for (let i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (elements[i].checked)
      return elements[i].value;
  }
  return 0;
}

function calc() {
  let result = +getRadioValue("aa") + +getRadioValue("bb");
  document.getElementById('trouble_itog').value = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="aa" value='1' onchange='calc()'>
<input type="radio" name="aa" value='2' onchange='calc()'>
<input type="radio" name="aa" value='3' onchange='calc()'>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="bb" value='1' onchange='calc()'>
<input type="radio" name="bb" value='2' onchange='calc()'>
<input type="radio" name="bb" value='3' onchange='calc()'>
<br/>

<input type='button' value='=' onclick='calc()'>
<input type="text" id='trouble_itog' readonly>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!